# Stable SQL Server stored procedure unusual drop in performance

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, sqlperformance

I'm experiencing a very strange issue in SQL Server 2005.

Yesterday users reported slowness in a specific part of our database app. I am not sure how pervasive the slowness is - it's definitely not everywhere, as this is the only part of the system reported - but I isolated the relevant stored procedure which used to run in 2-3 seconds and is now consistently running in 50-60 seconds.

It's a complex query -- multiple layers of subqueries. It returns only 42 rows in 16 columns.

The query looks like this:

```
select col1,2,3,4,5,...
from 
( select .... ) t
ORDER BY col1
```

I started picking apart the query to find out what was slow and found that removing the final `ORDER BY` clause brought the performance back in line.

This is highly mysterious. I could not replicate the problem on our DEV server. It's only 42 rows so the order by clause should be inconsequential. Execution plans are identical w/ and without the order by, and on the two servers.

Any brainstorming about what could have changed on our production server would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any number of things, but if its just this one query it might be outstanding write-locks - the query will be taking Read Locks unless you specify with (nolock) which is not necessarily a good thing. It could be Index Fragmentation on one of the tables too.

Comment: Do you have before and after execution plans to compare? Do you at least have an after execution plan to look at?

Comment: On prod now, Execution plans are identical between the versions with and without order by, with the addition of  last sort operator for the order by version. I generated an execution plan on DEV, where the problem isn't occurring, and it was identical as well.

Comment: Yeah you might try rebuilding your indexes.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER INDEX ALL ON BiggestTableInQuery
REBUILD;

Did the trick! It was horribly fragmented, 55-98% on 5 indexes, clustered 55%. So now I'm going to review other large tables as well.

Thanks simon at rcl and Tab Alleman!